# Iterating through a file and replacing old values with new values using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, scripting

Im trying to write a script in which a while loop reads a file line by line, performs a command on two values on that line (to get two new values), then replaces the two old values with the two new values, then moves on to the next line.

For example the txt file example.txt contains the following data:

```
 1432771200 != 1432800000 OPTION VALUE
 1432771200 != 1432800210 OPTION VALUE
 1432771200 != 1432800033 OPTION VALUE
```

And I run the following script:

```
 #!/bin/bash -x
 #
    while read line
    do
            arr=($line)
            CURRENTDATE=`h2e ${arr[0]}`
            PROPOSEDDATE=`h2e ${arr[2]}`
            echo $CURRENTDATE
            echo $PROPOSEDDATE
    #       echo $line |
            sed -i "s/${arr[0]}/$CURRENTDATE/"
    #       echo $line |
            sed -i "s/${arr[2]}/$PROPOSEDDATE/"
    done < /srg/pro/data/example.txt
```

What I expect to see now in example.txt file is the replacement of the first and third value on each line.. so it should look like this:

```
 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST != Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST OPTION VALUE
 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST != Wed May 27 01:00:00.000 2015 BST OPTION VALUE
 Fri May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST != Fri May 29 06:00:00.000 2015 BST OPTION VALUE
```

And so on and so forth..

When I run the shell script with `bash -x Interface.sh` Im getting this:

```
 read line
 + arr=($line)
 ++ h2e 1432771200
 + CURRENTDATE='1432771200.000  2015148  Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)'
 ++ h2e 1432800000
 + PROPOSEDDATE='1432800000.000  2015148  Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)'
  + echo 1432771200.000 2015148 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST '(1)'
   1432771200.000 2015148 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)
   + echo 1432800000.000 2015148 Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST '(1)'
   1432800000.000 2015148 Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)
 + sed -i 's/1432771200/1432771200.000  2015148  Thu May 28 01:00:00.000       2015 BST (1)/'
 sed: no input files
 + sed -i 's/1432800000/1432800000.000  2015148  Thu May 28 09:00:00.000   2015 BST (1)/'
 sed: no input files
 + read line
 + arr=($line)
 ++ h2e 1432771200
 + CURRENTDATE='1432771200.000  2015148  Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)'
 ++ h2e 1432800000
+ PROPOSEDDATE='1432800000.000  2015148  Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST  (1)'
 + echo 1432771200.000 2015148 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST '(1)'
 1432771200.000 2015148 Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)
 + echo 1432800000.000 2015148 Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST '(1)'
 1432800000.000 2015148 Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)
 + sed -i 's/1432771200/1432771200.000  2015148  Thu May 28 01:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)/'
 sed: no input files
+ sed -i 's/1432800000/1432800000.000  2015148  Thu May 28 09:00:00.000 2015 BST (1)/'
sed: no input files
```

Please help! Dont know how to fix this!

Comment: sed is mandatory or awk or other tools are available ?

Comment: No sed isnt mandatory..

Comment: So, if your local copy of `awk` has the built-in `strftime()` function, then you can do your processing all in one short `awk` script and with quite good speed and efficiency.  It is still possible with `sed` in a way similar to what you tried, but you want only one `sed` command, on the tail of the pipe from `echo` like you tried but commented out, and you need to use `-e` twice (once for each `s` expression), and no `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your batch (there are other way)

```
#!/bin/bash -x
 #
  cp /srg/pro/data/example.txt /tmp/temp.file

  cat /srg/pro/data/example.txt \
  | while read line
    do
            arr=($line)
            CURRENTDATE=`h2e ${arr[0]}`
            PROPOSEDDATE=`h2e ${arr[2]}`
            echo $CURRENTDATE
            echo $PROPOSEDDATE
    #       echo $line |
            sed -i "s/${arr[0]}\(.*\)${arr[2]}/${CURRENTDATE}\1${PROPOSEDDATE}/" /tmp/temp.file
    done

mv /tmp/temp.file /srg/pro/data/example.txt
```

- `sed -i` does not work on stream, need a file
- I use a temporary file to avoid problem reading the same file that is modified inside the loop that often create unexpected result (like empty file)
- this work for your sample but it depend of line structure for your array and sed substitution in real structure of data file

Comment: problem seems that there are several times the same CURRENTDATE  (and/or) proposed time and the sed change all occurence where you want to change only the same. I adapt the sed action to be more compliant to your need (takling the peer value as reference and not 2 single shoot)

Comment: This seems to be kinda working.. but not totally correct.. when I run the script for some reason it seems like its reading the line numerous times and prints out the replacement value multiple times

Comment: Its still printing the new value numerous times.. even with the change in the sed command

Comment: any output sample ? i retest here (with a quick *h2e* that change number to letter) and everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

The read command can read split the line into fields:

```
outfile=/tmp/some_tmp_file_you_will_move
while read date1 marker date2 otherfields; do
    CURRENTDATE=`h2e ${date1}`
    PROPOSEDDATE=`h2e ${date2}`
    echo $CURRENTDATE
    echo $PROPOSEDDATE
    echo "${CURRENTDATE} ${marker} ${PROPOSEDDATE} ${otherfields}" >> ${outfile}
done < /srg/pro/data/example.txt
```

When you don't need to see the CURRENTDATE/PROPOSEDDATE inside your loop, you can redirect the output outside the loop for a better performance:

```
outfile=/tmp/some_tmp_file_you_will_move
while read date1 marker date2 otherfields; do
    CURRENTDATE=`h2e ${date1}`
    PROPOSEDDATE=`h2e ${date2}`
    echo "${CURRENTDATE} ${marker} ${PROPOSEDDATE} ${otherfields}"
done < /srg/pro/data/example.txt > ${outfile}
```

Note: Consider using $(h2e ...) and not ``

Comment: seems request is more a generic info about *how to* using this sample data structure and your proposition work for it. You will modify nearly everything if structure is changed a bit.